# How to differentiate this function?[2nd derivative for multi variables]

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $f(x,y)$ with $x=x(s,t)$ and $y= y(s,t)$

By chain-rule, first derivative for $s$ would be

${\partial f \over \partial s} $ = ${\partial f \over \partial x} \bullet {dx \over ds} + {\partial f \over \partial y} \bullet {dy \over ds} $

So I tried the second derivative, under the condition that values of the ${dx \over ds}$ and  ${dy \over ds}$ are given.

But I couldn't find any idea and still nothing coming to mind for solving method.

What is the ${\partial ^2 f \over \partial s^2}$, ${\partial^2 f \over \partial^2 t} $ and ${\partial f \over \partial s \partial t } $ ?

Comment: Why this downvote ?

Comment: I don't know the exact reason why he/she did downvote. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

From

$$df=f_xdx+f_ydy$$

you draw 
$$f_s=f_x\frac{dx}{ds}+f_y\frac{dx}{ds}.$$

Then similarly by differentiating the products,

$$d{f_s}=(f_{xx}dx+f_{xy}dy)\frac{dx}{ds}+f_x\frac{d^2x}{ds}+(f_{yx}dy+f_{yy}dy)\frac{dy}{ds}+f_y\frac{d^2y}{ds}$$

and

$$f_{ss}=f_{xx}\left(\frac{dx}{ds}\right)^2+2f_{xy}\frac{dx}{ds}\frac{dy}{ds}+f_{yy}\left(\frac{dy}{ds}\right)^2+f_x\frac{d^2x}{ds^2}+f_y\frac{d^2y}{ds^2}$$

and similarly for the other partials.